# One of Multiple Partial String Matches R

Tags: r, regex, dataframe

I have a `data.frame` in which one column has names, some followed by a string of letters in parentheses. I want to remove these rows. So, for example:

```
> df

   Name              x1    x2
1  Michael (ACBFED)   3     5
2  Mickey (A)         4     1
3  Mike               2     7
4  Mick (RC)          8     6
```

I ultimately want:

```
   Name         x1    x2
3  Mike          2     7
```

Every string starts with "(A" or "(R", so I thought I could use grep to find "(A" or "(R", but I get an error saying I'm missing the corresponding ")". How would I restrict the search toba string starting and ending with parentheses?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide the code you have written so far so we can help see where you're going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say we have a `data.frame` like this one:

```
data <- data.frame(name=c("What", "Where (A)", "When (B)", "Why"), x1=1:4, x2=9:6)
> data
       name x1 x2
1      What  1  9
2 Where (A)  2  8
3  When (B)  3  7
4       Why  4  6
```

Trying to select rows using `grep`:

```
data[grep("(", data$name), ]
```

Doesn't work because `(` has a special meaning in regular expressions. We need to escape that character with `\\`:

```
> data[grep("\\(.*?\\)", data$name), ]
       name x1 x2
2 Where (A)  2  8
3  When (B)  3  7
```

NOTE: `.*?\\)` here means match any number of any symbols until the first closing `)`

This works but selects the rows with `()` rather than removing it. We can add `invert=TRUE` to get what we need:

```
> data[grep("\\(.*?\\)", data$name, invert=TRUE), ]
  name x1 x2
1 What  1  9
4  Why  4  6
```